# How to handle a boss that I believe is non-maliciously setting me up for failure?

Tags: work-environment, united-states, mistakes

I have been working with a company for about 6 months, with the job title of software engineer/support specialist. So far, I have done very little software work, but that was initially expected.

The problem is with my boss, the owner of the company. I'm expected to support their software to corporate customers with very little assistance. The previous support employee left several months before I started, and the only other person able to help me is doing field work 90% of the time. He is unreachable almost all of the time when he's doing field work.

My boss tells me to "jump into the thick of it and get my hands dirty" to learn the software. If a customer contacts me, I'm supposed to learn as I go to fix it. I had no problem doing this, but a couple weeks ago, I made a change that broke the customer's systems for 4 days. Eventually the field guy had to fix it when he had time. Now just two days ago, the system broke again even after I was being very careful. The boss is blaming me when I feel I haven't had the resources to succeed. He mentioned to me that "this system has been working for years and is now breaking", implying that I'm the cause.

Another issue is that I have a couple of actual software projects that I haven't had any chance to start. The customers are waiting for work to be completed, but I just haven't had time due to my support load. I probably would have time if I was more knowledgeable of the software, but even after 6 months I'm not up to speed with how to fix things quickly.

How should I handle this? Should I bring it up to my boss and what should I say? He's very headstrong.

Comment: What if the case is simply that they are not the right place for you and/or you are not the right support for them. I would look for another job without trying to fix this.

Comment: @SandraK This has crossed my mind, but it is custom software. The developers unintentionally made it so that it's very hard to support.

Comment: @erik - **"unintentionally made it so that it's very hard to support."** <- what you mean to say is that it's poorly designed. Nothing "unintentional" about it.

Comment: yeah @Erik, this does not make any sense. If you want to grow, find a professional place

Comment: @AndreiROM You're right. I was brought on to help create the "next version". However, my boss doesn't want to dedicate me to do that yet or spend the money.

Comment: @erik - I've heard this stuff so many times that it has become a meme. Small company creates a product with decent potential, but poorly implemented. Rather than taking the time to fix it, or build the next gen well, they tack on functionality, all the while operating with like 1 programmer/server expert who is underpaid, and leaves the second he can. Owner - who is clueless about programming - then hires a junior dev to take on the role, promises the sky, design of new system etc, while you actually end up mired in supporting the dying software, and being blamed for the failure. 1/2

Comment: 2/2  I've worked for two companies where that was the case (one was essentially a clone of the situation you're in, the other was bigger, and the dysfunction was a little more subtle). Almost every programmer I know has worked for at least one such horror story of a company (early in their careers). You learn to recognize them, and to know that you have no chance to ever get anything truly productive done there. Just look for a new job and chalk it up as a learning experience.

Comment: Don't do like your boss and try to fix a dying situation ;) just "_build the new you_" by finding another job..

Comment: @AndreiROM Your assessment is fairly accurate, but he does pay me fairly well or at least in line with the market. The owner was a programmer, but hasn't programmed since the 90's. It sounds like I should polish up my resume and begin searching again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The 90's were the wild west of programming. There were no well established coding standards, or people hadn't heard of them / weren't using them, etc. In other words this guy is probably 20 years out of date, and has about as much to contribute to a good design as your average construction worker. Glad to hear you're getting decent pay, but if you could get the same amount elsewhere then why suffer through the stress and finger pointing? The only reason to stick around is if you stand to learn a lot, or if you have little to no experience and can't really land a better position.

Comment: I've been in a similar situation, except it wasn't in software development, but in e-sports. I hope this is not relevant for you, but I'll share it just in case it is. Don't make my mistake, remember that this is NOT YOUR FAULT. Don't let them brainwash you into believing that it is. It is NOT your fault, regardless of what they say.

Answer (score 19):

What you've told us is what you should be telling him as well. However, more importantly, you should be looking for a new job.

These sort of chaotic workplaces may serve to teach you a lot, but are usually not worth the stress, and not all of those skills and habits you pick up may be good ones. Especially when you have the threat of being fired for your boss's failings hanging over your head.

I would look for a sane employer, with more staff, where you can actually get some training. In the mean time keep telling your boss that you need more training and help, but your requests will likely fall on deaf ears.

Comment: +1 because I believe the answer is: "_you should be looking for a new job._" instead of trying to fix a dying situation (just like their software)

Comment: This, so much this. And don't stick around to try and fix it. OP, take it from another person who has been in your situation and stuck around: it will go wrong and *you* will be blamed. There is no fixing this. Run, don't walk.

Answer (score 2):

I have to disagree with the other answer.

What you have described to me is this: the only free resource to handle these issues is you. this makes you hard to fire. Use it.

This is where you will learn the most. Yes, you might get fired. Yes, the stakes are high, and you will take the heat. But this heat is what you learn from. Fear of failure is the mother of all invention, almost. I have always come out with a fresh perspective after going into the deep end. Some I failed. Learn to accept failure as a learning experience and use the motivation it gives you both up front and in hindsight. This will prepare you to handle greater projects in the future. I was luckily once put in charge of a pilot process because there were no others available. Holy batman we screwed up alot, but in doing so learned enough about the process to defend a 500 MUSD capex investment.

Stick with it.

Edit: As an addendum, build relations with your customers and clients instead of your boss given your situation.

Comment: I disagree. Failure is okay, if the boss understands that it is part of the process. That doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @Belle-sophie well, we agree to disagree then. Having no challenges under the worlds best boss gets you nowhere. Getting fired is not the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try an look at this situation objectively.

You haven't specified the role that you applied for, i.e. was it a trainee software engineer/support specialist or was the role advertised as an experienced engineer.

Either way communication is key, but explaining that you are not happy because of X isn't necessarily the best way to handle things.

instead try putting half an hour of your own time in to writing a handover/update of your day to your employer. It may go something like this;

Today I have spoken to X customers, of which I was able help X I spent longer than I should have with customer X as I wasn't sure on what to do, after researching/contacting/asking for help I come to the conclusion X.

I definitely think there is in an opportunity for me to gain a deeper understanding around X issue, please could you advise the best way for me to get this information.

I also have X projects which I need to start and have customers waiting for however due to X time researching/contacting/asking for help today I was unable to start today. I'm starting to worry that I am falling behind with these projects, please could you advise on what YOU think I should do.

Comment: Why "in your own time"? This seems like a perfectly valid way to use working hours.

Comment: When you are falling behind at work sometimes adding another job to your list can make it seem less realistic, doing this in your own time gives you the ability to feel as if you have gone above and beyond in showing your decision making and opportunities for development, this will show the employer your commitment and make you feel somewhat better about the situation when it comes to a review. However I do believe it to be perfectly acceptable in work time to do this, it's just how I would handle this situation

Answer (score 0):

One other approach I've not seen mentioned is to push your employer to hire more people to share the support workload so you can have some time to focus on some building.